# Using GNU Make to build both debug and release targets at the same time (Extended)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I would like to follow up on [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035013/using-gnu-make-to-build-both-debug-and-release-targets-at-the-same-time)... Now that I can build two different executables, I would like to build the executables in different directories, depending on a variable.

I would like to go from something like:

```
EXEDIR     = bin/release/
EXE        = $(EXEDIR)AmiModRadio
SOURCES    = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTSDIR = o/release/
OBJECTS    = $(addprefix $(OBJECTSDIR), $(SOURCES:.c=.o))

CC = vbcc:bin/vc
LD = vbcc:bin/vc

release : $(EXE) 
$(OBJECTS) : $(OBJECTSDIR)%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(shell vbccprefs) -c $< -o $@
$(EXE) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(shell vbccprefs) -o $(EXE) $(OBJECTS)
```

to something like:

```
EXE        = $(EXEDIR)AmiModRadio
SOURCES    = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS    = $(addprefix $(OBJECTSDIR), $(SOURCES:.c=.o))

CC = vbcc:bin/vc
LD = vbcc:bin/vc

release : EXEDIR = bin/release/
release : OBJECTSDIR = o/release/
release : $(EXE) 

release : EXEDIR = bin/debug/
release : OBJECTSDIR = o/debug/
release : $(EXE) 

$(OBJECTS) : $(OBJECTSDIR)%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(shell vbccprefs) -c $< -o $@
$(EXE) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(shell vbccprefs) -o $(EXE) $(OBJECTS)
```

The last makefile above does not work because, as I understand it, setting the variables `EXEDIR` and `OBJECTSDIR` in the rules `release` and `debug` is too late.

So, am I missing something simple here? Is there a way to have the two rules `release` and `debug` use the same rules but generate the files in two different sets of directories, including the executables that are the main targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a conditional to determine what the target is and set the variables accordingly.

```
ifeq "$(strip $(filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))" "debug"
EXEDIR = bin/release/
OBJECTSDIR = o/release/
endif
ifeq "$(strip $(filter release,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))" "release"
EXEDIR = bin/debug/
OBJECTSDIR = o/debug/
endif
```

The big issue that I see with your code is that you are specifying the release target on both the release and debug paths.  So GNU Make uses the last assignment that it encounters.  But, using what I have here should work as I do something similar with my make files.

In doing this, you cannot specify release and debug on the command line at the same time as they are mutually exclusive.  The strip function strips out the leading and trailing whitespace from the parameter, which is the output of the filter function.  The filter function takes the string debug and looks for it in the pre-defined variable MAKECMDGOALS.  MAKECMDGOALS is a list of all the goals (targets) that was specified on the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your help, with you help and Ziffusion's, my makefile works and with minimal changes to my build chain

Answer (score 5):

You can invoke the following Makefile as:

```
make release
make debug
```

-- OR --

```
make BUILD=release
make BUILD=debug
```

**Makefile**

```
ifneq ($(BUILD),release)
    BUILD = debug
endif

EXEDIR      = bin/$(BUILD)/
OBJDIR      = o/$(BUILD)/

EXE         = $(EXEDIR)AmiModRadio
SOURCES     = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS     = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(SOURCES:.c=.o))

CC = vbcc:bin/vc
LD = vbcc:bin/vc

CFLAGS  = $(shell vbccprefs)
LDFLAGS = $(shell vbccprefs)

all : $(EXE)

.PHONY : release debug    
release debug :
    $(MAKE) BUILD=$@

$(EXE) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJDIR)%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: Thank you Ziffusion, with your help and Daniels' below, I manage to get my makefile to work exactly as I want. I accept Daniel's answer because it does not require "BUILD=" (somehow $(BUILD) is empty when doing `make release` or `make debug`)

Comment: That's fine. But note that the `Makefile` does not require `BUILD=<type>' to be passed in. My first solution did, but I changed it. In any case, it's good to know both the approaches.